# elastic4s 6.2.2 HttpClient issues

Tags: elastic4s

Recently I found out that elastic4s `TcpClient` is deprecated and going to be removed in 7.x versions.
I tried to migrate to `HttpClient` and faced the following issue; suppose we have a following insert operation:

```
val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(elasticUri))  
def insert(ent: MyEntity): Future[Either[RequestFailure, RequestSuccess[Nothing]]] =  
  client.execute {indexInto(myIndex) doc ent}
```

This raises compile error:

> Error:(27, 49) could not find implicit value for parameter exec:
>   com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpExecutable[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.indexes.IndexDefinition,U]

Could someone please explain what is HttpExecutable and how it should be initialized?
PS: elastic4s version is 6.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was my fault actually...
I imported `ElasticApi._` instead of `ElasticDsl._` and it caused this issue.
So in total there is no issue at all

Comment: How to create template using elastic4s from raw json having setting and mapping details.